# Is "exclaim to" correct?

Tags: reported-speech

Sunil said to his friend, "**look out! Be careful keep away from the wire**".

- a) sunil exclaimed with surprise to his friend to be careful and keep away from the wire.
- b) sunil exclaimed with surprise and said to his friend to be careful and keep away from the wire.

Which one is correct in indirect speech?

Is it right to say, "*exclaimed to someone*"?

Answer (score 1):

"Exclaimed" in this case refers to the "way" he communicated, so it could be compared to Yelled, Screamed, Shouted, and in different context, Whispered, Mumbled, etc.

## 1 is correct.

Comment: #2 is not incorrect

Comment: @J.R Why #2 is correct.

Comment: @1010 - It all depends on how it's parsed. Imagine: _Sunil exclaimed with surprise! He said to his friend to be careful and keep away form the wire._ (Granted, it's not exactly elegant, but I'm not sure I'd say it's "wrong".)

Comment: I figured we were choosing which was best out of the 2 sentences, rather than re-writing them.. :)  That being said, @J.R.'s alternate (sentence #3) sounds better than #1 or #2.   Also (re: _"not wrong"_, On this site I find myself regularly sharing my opinion that, unless a person's going to be an English Professor, "perfect grammar" is becoming less and less of a necessity (or a reality).  It's more important that others understand _what_ we are trying to communicate, not _how perfectly_ we say it (especially in the world of texting, emails, forums, etc...

Comment: @ashleedawg - As for that tension between understandable and grammatical, I try to be careful with that. On one hand, I don't want to give our learners the impression that it'd be okay if we all start speaking like internet cats ("Can I haz cheezeburger, pleeze?"). On the other hand, I don't want to be a pendant and claim something is unequivocally wrong when there may be a contrived context where it's okay, or when it could be made right with improved punctuation or some other minor adjustment. Moreover, some grammatical rules are really just myths, so, all told, there is plenty to discuss.

Comment: @J.R. I absolutely agree. It's interesting to see how much side-discussion (+ learning) take places between "native speakers", from a question posted by an "English Learner" on this site.  I, too, believe there is a "line" between understandable and grammatical and by no means know its location.  Hopefully "our learners" consider both approaches (which is arguably the ideal way to learn _anything_,) There's benefit to being able to interpret "Can I haz cheezeburger" (might end up working at McD's!), as well as to understanding what's wrong with the sentence (might end up President of McD's!)